# Hanging list bullets with column-count in WebKit

Tags: html, css, webkit, column-count

In Chrome and Safari, the following code to have **[hanging punctuation](http://www.markboulton.co.uk/journal/five-simple-steps-to-better-typography-part-2)** in lists, as well as CSS3 multiple columns, hides the list bullets. Works as expected in Firefox (with `-moz-column-count`).

```
<style>
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 2
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>

<div>
    <p>hello world</p> 
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ul>
    <p>hello world</p> 
</div>
```

Is this a known bug? I can't seem to find a workaround.

Note: I want hanging bullets (green), not indented bullets (red):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this..

```
ul {
    list-style: disc outside none; 
    margin-left: 0; 
    padding-left: 1em;
}
li {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
p{
    padding-left:2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vishnurajv/LB7Rc/